# What does index $\mu$ in $\partial_{\mu}$ mean?

Tags: field-theory, notation, differentiation

I am a **beginner** in QFT, and  am reading it from Quantum Field Theory Demystified by David McGowan,  a Tata McGraw-Hill publication.

Here, in this book, the author at one point, while explaining Laggan giant Field Theory,  writes that the first derivative of a field  $\varphi $ is denoted by $\partial _\mu \varphi $. What does the $\mu $ mean?

A screenshot is attached:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Physics notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331750)

Comment: Hi Wrichik. The question I've linked doesn't have a very useful title, but it asks exactly the same question as you.

Comment: Please don't post texts you want to quote as screenshots, but *type them out instead* since images cannot be searched by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136).

Comment: I knew everybody here were already familiar with the notation. I just posted a screenshot for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial_\mu$ is a short-hand for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$, the partial derivative with respect to the $\mu^{\mathrm{th}}$ space-time coordinate. Similarly, 
$$\partial^\mu = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu} = \eta^{\mu \nu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu},$$
where $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ is the inverse of the [Minkowski metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Minkowski_metric) and the [Einstein summation convention](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html) is used.